# How to unzip a numpy.ndarray and convert it into another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having some problems when I try to load a numpy.ndarray and convert it into a new array. The new array should show the same data in the numpy.ndarray.

First, I use `zip()` to combine my rows, columns, and weightings.

```
for connName in save_conns:
        conn = connections[connName]
        connListSparse = zip(conn.i[:], conn.j[:], conn.w[:])
        np.save(data_path + 'weights/' + connName + ending, connListSparse)
```

Then, I use `list()` to print connListSparse. It shows [(0, 0, 0.1), (0, 1, 0.3), (1, 0, 0.8), (1, 1, 0.7)].

However, after I `np.load()` the .npy file and try to convert it into a new array, it shows an error.

```
readout = np.load(fileName)
print(readout.shape, fileName)     #readout.shape=()
value_arr = np.zeros((n_src, n_tgt))     #n_src=2, n_tgt=2
if not readout.shape == (0,):
        value_arr[np.int32(readout[:,0]), np.int32(readout[:,1])] = readout[:,2]
return value_arr
```

I dig into the code and find that when I try `unzipped_readout = zip(*readout)`, it returns `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array`.

I'm sure that my data path is correct. But the new array cannot load the data.

I'm using python 3.7.10, numpy 1.16.1, brian2 2.4.2.

I'm a beginner in this community. Let me know if you want more information about the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at `connListSparse` before saving?  While the `list(connListSparse)` may look right, that's not what you saved.

Comment: I think you want to use `np.save(filename, row=conn.i, col=conn.j, wgt=conn.w)`.  Read the `savez` docs.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are confusing the python `zip()` with the `zip` archive produced by `np.savez`.

```
In [529]: zipobj = zip(np.arange(3), np.ones(3))
In [530]: zipobj
Out[530]: <zip at 0x7fc5dceb05c0>
In [531]: list(zipobj)
Out[531]: [(0, 1.0), (1, 1.0), (2, 1.0)]
```

saving `zipobj` is not the same as saving the list created from it.

```
In [532]: np.save('test.npy',zipobj)
In [533]: data = np.load('test.npy', allow_pickle=True)
In [534]: data
Out[534]: array(<zip object at 0x7fc5dc85e440>, dtype=object)
```

Even if all pickle, the load zip object is not the same as the original, and thus is empty.

```
In [536]: data.item()
Out[536]: <zip at 0x7fc5dc85e440>
In [537]: list(_)
Out[537]: []
```

But using the `savez` we can save a zip archive containing arrays:

```
In [538]: np.savez('test.npz', x=np.arange(3), y=np.ones(3))
In [539]: data = np.load('test.npz')
In [540]: data
Out[540]: <numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile at 0x7fc5dfac4eb0>

In [546]: list(data.keys())
Out[546]: ['x', 'y']
In [547]: data['x']
Out[547]: array([0, 1, 2])
In [548]: data['y']
Out[548]: array([1., 1., 1.])
```

you can also use a OS file archive tool to see that `test.npz` contains 2 files, `x.npy` and `y.npy`.  Those are loaded with the `data['x']` syntax.

---

Alternative savings:

```
In [549]: alist = [np.arange(3), np.ones(3)]
In [550]: np.save('test.npy',alist)
In [551]: data = np.load('test.npy', allow_pickle=True)
In [552]: data
Out[552]: 
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Since the 2 arrays matched in shape, it actually saved `np.array(alist)` which is a (2,3) float array.

Alternatively we can make an object dtype array:

```
In [553]: arr = np.array([None,None])
In [554]: arr[:] = alist
In [555]: arr
Out[555]: array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([1., 1., 1.])], dtype=object)
In [556]: np.save('test.npy',arr)
In [557]: data = np.load('test.npy', allow_pickle=True)
In [558]: data
Out[558]: array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([1., 1., 1.])], dtype=object)
```

---

I wonder if you are confused about that `zip` does?  Maybe this simple application to two list gives a clearer idea:

```
In [560]: zip([1,2,3],[4,5,5])
Out[560]: <zip at 0x7fc5dce2b680>
In [561]: list(zip([1,2,3],[4,5,5]))
Out[561]: [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 5)]
```

I think of that as a list version of `transpose`, pairing elements of the arrays.  In Py3, `zip` just sets up that action, the `list` (or other iteration) is required to actual do the pairing.

Comment: Hello, hpaulj!
I've tried to use `np.savez()` and it works.
I really appreciate your solution.
Thank you.